# How can I make a wp site in a mobile application?

Tags: mobile, iphone, third-party-applications, android

Which are the ways and how is possible a wp site become an iphone, ipad, android and a blackberry application(not a wp mobile theme)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WordPress is a set of PHP scripts running on a web server. So your application needs a web server, a data base and PHP. I don’t think this is possible on all of those platforms.

Comment: Can you suggest me a tutorial or a company or someone who is able to do that?

Comment: @Alex No, sorry. Also, I think, web apps are the future. Managing separate apps for every platform just doesn’t pay off.

Comment: So an app can be created in order to be used in all the platforms the same?

Comment: An offline app probably not. For online work you just need a mobile interface. There are already some apps which do that.

Comment: so the offline is the mobiles apps and the mobile interface is the mobile themes right?

Comment: @Alex You can make your online interface work [offline too](http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/). But it is still an interface written in HTML, CSS and JavaScript delivered by a website, not something the user has to install.

Answer (score 2):

To build it you can use [hookpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hookpress/) or the [json api](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/). You would need to built a stand alone app and then query wordpress for the info you want, using the above two plugins makes that a lot easier, in effect you turning wordpress into an API.

An update to this post since I comes up via the googles:

Java for WordPress xmlrpc.

http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-java/

Comment: Just as I have asked the previous user "can you suggest me a tutorial or a company or someone who is able to do that?"

Comment: I don't know any tutorials, and this is not the place to ask for work, any developer with mobile experience could do this, my advice look from someone that lives near you and go meet them.

Comment: @wyck The only problem with JSON API is that it afaik doesn't support custom post types.

Comment: Oh bummer that is good to know, I have not used it for a while.